# Change css through jquery after a click on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code isn't working, Is there anything wrong in this code, when I click on div.first it has to show div.second and a click again should make it display none.

Html

```
<div class="first">some text</div>
<div class ="second">bunch of text</div>
```

Css

```
.second{display=none;}
```

Jquery

```
 $('.first').click(function() {
  $('.second').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Missing. change this  `$('second').css('display', 'block');` to  `$('.second').css('display', 'block');`

Comment: Thats a typo, its not the actual problem, thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.toggle()` to toggle `display`

```js
$('.first').click(function() {
  $('.second').toggle();
});
```

```css
.second{display=none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">some text</div>
<div class ="second">bunch of text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use classes to hide and show Elements

HTML

```
<div class="first">some text</div>
<div class ="second div-hide">bunch of text</div>
```

CSS

```
.div-hide{display:none}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.first').click(function() {
   if ($('.second').hasClass('div-hide'))
   {
        $('.second').removeClass('div-hide');
   }
   else
   {
       $('.second').addClass('div-hide');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JQuery, you forgot the period in front of `second`

```
$('.first').click(function() {
     $('.second').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$('.second').toggle();`

```js
 $('.first').click(function() {
  $('.second').toggle();
});
```

```css
.second{display=none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">some text</div>
<div class ="second">bunch of text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need this

```
$('.first').click(function() {
  $('.second').toggle();
});
```

Here is an example

```js
$('.first').click(function() {
  $('.second').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first">some text</div>
<div class ="second">bunch of text</div>
```