# Toggle() function is not working in accordion

Tags: jquery, html

`Onclick` of `(.cancel-name)` <kbd>cancel</kbd> button which is inside of `panel-body`, `panel-body` has to get hide and I have used `toggle` function for that and it is working fine. But, after that edit is not working once if the page is refreshed edit will work can anyone help me out from this?

**view page**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading row">
            <div class="col-md-4">First Name</div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></div>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <div class="col-md-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                        <label class="col-md-4">First Name</label>              
                        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                            <input type ="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>"/></br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                            <!--                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="" id="">Save</button>-->
                            <button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    var event = 'click';
    var speed = "500";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.cancel-name').on(event, function () {
            $("div.panel-body").toggle();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have `click event` to `toggle` collapsing `panel` on cancel. Just add `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes to `cancel button` as you have it for **<kbd>Edit</kbd>** button:

**Example:**

```
<button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading row">
      <div class="col-md-4">First Name</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        John Doe
      </div>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="col-md-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
            <label class="col-md-4">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>" /><br/>
              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;" />
              <!--                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="" id="">Save</button>-->
              <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The use of toggle () is not enabled for Jquery 1.9 or higher, you can solve it by use Jquery migrate.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

It is advisable to use classes to hide or show elements
[Change css through jquery after a click on a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442894/change-css-through-jquery-after-a-click-on-a-div/44443395#44443395)